# Does static_cast makes the compiler allocate more space than what it is meant to by new operator?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, memory, static-cast

I have written a **Base** class and a **Derived** class with the respective data members as you could see in the code below. Now in main function I have created new **Base** class objects pointed by **Derived** class pointers using static_cast for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
class Base {
public:
  int b;
  Base() : b(2){};
  int get_b() const;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
  int d;
  Derived() : d(4){};
  int get_d() const;
};

int Base::get_b() const { return b; }

int Derived::get_d() const { return d; }

int main() {
  std::vector<Derived *> bArray;
  bArray.push_back(static_cast<const Derived *>(new Base()));
  bArray.push_back(static_cast<const Derived *>(new Base()));

  std::vector<Derived *>::iterator bArrayIt = bArray.begin();
  for (; bArrayIt != bArray.end(); ++bArrayIt) {
    std::cout << (*bArrayIt)->get_b() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*bArrayIt)->get_d() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2
0
```

Now in the code I have tried accessing the data members of the **derived** class using the **Derived** pointers but I expected it to return a compilation error or 'ArrayOutOfBoundIndex' or segmentation_fault because the object is of **Base** type as space is allocated for base object only but instead got value of that member 'd' as zero. According to what I know about **static_cast** it just alters the pointer type and not allocate memory,but here not only we could access the memory not allocated but the value has been set to 0 initially beforehand, so I did a small experiment of my own.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class State;
class Base;
class Derived;
class State {
public:
  static bool flag;
};
bool State::flag = true;

class Base : public State {
public:
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  Base() : a(2), b(4), c(16){};

  int get_a() { return a; }
  int get_b() { return b; }
  int get_c() { return c; }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  int d;
  int e;
  int f;
  Derived() : d(6), e(8), f(12){};
  int set_d(int ds) { d = ds; }
  int get_d() { return d; }

  int get_e() { return e; }
  int get_f() { return f; }
};

int main() {
  Derived *d[2];

  d[0] = static_cast<Derived *>(new Base());
  d[1] = static_cast<Derived *>(new Base());

  std::cout << d[0]->get_a() << std::endl;
  std::cout << d[0]->get_d() << std::endl;
  d[0]->set_d(100);
  std::cout << d[0]->get_d() << std::endl;
  int *i = reinterpret_cast<int *>(d[0]);
  std::cout << (*i) << std::endl;
  i++;
  std::cout << (*i) << std::endl;

  i++;
  std::cout << (*i) << std::endl;

  i++;
  std::cout << (*i) << std::endl;

  i++;
  std::cout << (*i) << std::endl;

  i++;
  std::cout << (*i) << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Let's move onto d[1]" << std::endl;
  int *j = reinterpret_cast<int *>(d[1]);
  std::cout << (*j) << std::endl;
  j++;

  std::cout << (*j) << std::endl;
  j++;

  std::cout << (*j) << std::endl;
  j++;

  std::cout << (*j) << std::endl;

  j++;
  std::cout << (*j) << std::endl;
  j++;

  std::cout << (*j) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
2
0
100
2
4
16
100
0
0
Let's move into d[1]
2 
4
16
0
0
0
```

The output was according to what I got before.

**My Questions**:

1. Why is the variable allowed to access memory which is not allocated by the new keyword or the compiler and how is it able to do so?
2. If it is able to access memory location why doesn't the compiler give any runtime error or compile time error and is there any method to make the compiler do so?
3. Now if the memory is allocated by the compiler or somehow, what implications does it have on the memory i.e. if the Base class is of 12 bytes and the Derived class is of 24 bytes then will every object creation of Base Type and using static_cast for it to be pointed by Derived pointer will allocate 24 bytes of memory?

Comment: Not all errors in C++ are required to produce a hard failure. Sometimes it can just carry on doing the wrong thing without telling you.

Comment: When you have undefined behaviour, the compiler isn't required to emit an error. C++ has many such examples. It is best to learn from a reliable source rather than trial-and-error and wonder.

Comment: `static_cast<const Derived *>(new Base())` - you have a pointer to `Base` and then you lie to the compiler and say _"hey lets pretend this is actually a pointer to `Derived`"_. When you finally dereference the stored pointer you get Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Tip: If you want to inspect memory, do it as `char*`. That's frequently legal, and you won't get weird numbers like `4278255360` when it's just `0xFF 0x00 0xFF 0x00` you're looking at. That said, your program still has UB because of the invalid `static_cast`, so observing its behavior is meaningless.

Comment: For efficiency reasons (there could be others, but I think this is the main one) C++ compilers not obligated to prevent you to create code with Undefined Behavior or to produce any diagnostics either runtime or compile time. It is your job as a developer to avoid that..

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Why is the variable allowed to access memory which is not allocated by the new keyword or the compiler and how is it able to do so?

Because, there is nothing which will prevent you from doing it. C++ gives a lot of freedom for programmers, but with this freedom comes responsibility (e.g. making sure that you don't access unallocated memory).

> 2. If it is able to access memory location why doesn't the compiler give any runtime error or compile time error?

It's Undefined Behaviour, which means, that at runtime your program becomes unpredictable. If you're lucky, it may crash for some reason (e.g. segfault), but it doesn't have to. At compile time, this operation is prefectly legal in terms of language, so there is nothing compiler will complain about. You'll probably have to use some static analysis tool to catch such mistakes.

> 3. Now if the memory is allocated by the compiler or somehow, what implications does it have on the memory i.e. if the Base class is of 12 bytes and the Derived class is of 24 bytes then will every object creation of Base Type and using static_cast for it to be pointed by Derived pointer will allocate 24 bytes of memory?

`static_cast` has nothing to do with memory allocation. It just converts type of pointer. Allocating memory for object is up to `operator new` and size of memory allocated won't be affected by any pointer conversion.

Comment: Just to add, your "new Base" is allocating 4 bytes of memory, but if you did new "new Derived" it would allocate 8 bytes (assuming 4 bytes per int). However, most memory allocators in C++ allocate on boundaries of 16 bytes, so technically you are outside of the size of Base when you use it as Derived, I doubt you would ever crash, unless you use a memory allocator that can actually just allocate a 4 byte block (which could happen on some platforms), then your get_d() might be accessing memory allocated to something else which could be bad.